# only display hello world when I run example of RinSim ubuntu 64

Tags: rinsim

Hello I try to run the first example introduced in http://rinsim.rinde.nl/installation/intellij/, 
it shows the following error:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details.

then I add slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar and it can run without bug.

But, in the simulator there is only hello world, not any other things (such as the red points) what would be the problem? I use ubuntu 64 and intelliJ.
plus I do not use the option -XstartOnFirstThread as the introduction because it will fail with error: Unrecognized option: -
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the SLF4J issue, this is not a bug (see [troubleshooting](http://rinsim.rinde.nl/installation/troubleshooting/)). This message indicates that no logger implementation is found. If you don't want logging, you can safely ignore this.

As for the lack of red dots, RinSim starts in 'paused' mode, have you tried starting the simulator (using the shortcut: `Cmd-P` or `Ctrl-P` or via the menu: `Control` -> `Play`)?

Comment: Hey could you tell me how to start the simulator by Cmd-p or Control -> play?

Comment: I clarified the explanation, Cmd-P is for Mac OS, Ctrl-P for other OSes.